# Transfer data from from one sheet to another based on combobox value in excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have 2 sheets and a userform in my workbook.

Sheet1,has 3 rows which contains shift type info.(A2=A,A3=B and A4=C),I also have additional data in col B (start time),col C (end Time) and so on..

I use a form to enter employee names(txtName) and their shift type(cboShift) in sheet 2. col A= name and col B=shift type) now i want when i complete the employee data in shift 2,by clicking UPDATE button their relevant shift info(start time,end time...) from sheet 1 copied into next cells.

```
 Private Sub cmdUpdate_Click()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rgnSearch As Range
    Dim rngFound As Range

    Set ws1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet2")

    LastRow = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows2.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
    ws2.Range("A" & LastRow).Value = Me.txtName.Text
    ws1.Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.cboShift.Text

    Set rgnSearch = ws1.Range("A1", ws1.Cells(Rows2.Count, 1).End(xlUp))

    With rgnSearch
        Set rngFound = .Find(Me.txtName.Text, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            ws1.Range("C" & rngFound.row & ":F" & rngFound.row).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("C" & LastRow)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
End Sub
```

I have header in both sheets.

When i run the code i get error "method or data member not found).

```
LastRow = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.**Rows2**.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
```

My next question is: is there any way to transfer data for each person when i click ADD Button instead of doing it after for all 
Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably meant

```
LastRow = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
```

instead of

```
LastRow = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows2.Count).End(xlUp).row + 1
```

Comment: with your correction,now  i get run time error no: 424 "object required with this line  `Set rgnSearch = ws1.Range("A", ws1.Cells(Rows2.Count, 1).End(xlUp))`

Comment: remove the 2 after rows in rows2

Answer (score 1):

The error caused already answered in @h2so4 above.

However, a few things to consider in your code:

1. `ws1.Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.cboShift.Text` , not sure it's the same `LastRow` for both `ws1` ans `ws2` , is it ???
2. Once you already have a successful find, in `If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then` , you can use a different coding to copy the contents of cells C:F of the same row.

Instead of:

```
ws1.Range("C" & rngFound.row & ":F" & rngFound.row).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("C" & LastRow)
```

You can use:

```
rngFound.Offset(, 2).Resize(1, 4).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("C" & LastRow)
```

Comment: i changed `ws1.Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.cboShift.Text`

Comment: @Mansour changed it to what ?

Comment: i changed `ws1.Range("A" & LastRow).Offset(0, 1).Value = Me.cboShift.Text` to `ws2.Range(".......` so i got 1 step closer to my goal,but the main problem  that i also had before is copy is done if only i enter one of A,B,or C characters in txtName box ,but i want enter employee names and in that cace nothing happens.The code should check cboShift data (A-c) with sheet 1 col A range A2:A4 then copy relevent next cells data in sheet 2

Comment: I changed `Set rngFound = .Find(Me.txtName.Text, LookIn:=xlValues)`    with `Set rngFound = .Find(Me.cboShift.Text, LookIn:=xlValues)` so the code works properly now. thanks to @h2so4 and @shai

Comment: I've already up voted @h2so4 and now you but i really don't know to mark which answer